# localhost refused in android studio

Tags: php, android, json, wampserver

I am using wampserver  and trying fetch record from server using php script through json parsing. And I want to display that data on my android app....

My script code is clear and it worked perfect..And I am also clear with android code. But when I run my app the data is not display on my app....

**This is my android code....**

```
package com.example.abc.testdatabase;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestExternalDatabaseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView resultView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED
   resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    getData();
}

public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/getAllCustomers.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
}
//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
}

//parse json data
       try {
       String s = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       s = s + 
               "Name : "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n"+
               "Qualification : "+json.getInt("Qualification")+"\n"+
               "Mobile Using : "+json.getString("Mobile")+"\n\n";
       }

      resultView.setText(s);

   } catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
   }

    }

  }
```

**Following is error I am facing...........**

```
Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type    java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**Following is my php script...........**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 

}
 mysql_select_db("testDatabase", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
       $output[]=$row;
 }
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I don't understand why I am not getting any records....
If anyone round this then please help for this.....

```
Log.e................
     <br />
     <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr'            border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
     <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span   style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )   </span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will   be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in  C:\wamp\www\TestDatabase\connection.php on line <i>3</i></th></tr>
     <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
     <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
     <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0170</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>135864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\TestDatabase\getAllCustomer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getAllCustomer.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
     <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0190</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>137344</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>include_once( <font color='#00bb00'>'C:\wamp\www\TestDatabase\connection.php'</font> )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\TestDatabase\getAllCustomer.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getAllCustomer.php<b>:</b>4</td></tr>
     <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0190</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>137528</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
(  )   </td><td title='C:\wamp\www\TestDatabase\connection.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\connection.php<b>:</b>3</td></tr>
       </table></font>
      [{"FirstName":"Vandana    ","LastName":"Rao","Qualification":"MscICT","Mobile":"Sony Xepri"}]
      03-23 10:29:26.965    2426-2426/com.example.abc.testdatabase E/log_tag﹕   Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String   cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244516/jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarr)

Comment: You are receiving more than your JSON string as a response from your PHP file. From what I can see, there is an extra PHP warning stating "Deprecated: mysql_connect()..." and so on which is also being returned in addition to your JSON string. First take care of this warning from your PHP end then check if only a pure JSON string is being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<br` part of the exception indicates that the response you get is not a json response, but rather html.
I would guess that your result is an exception (or the output from `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());`).

Log the `result` string before trying to parse it, and I'm sure you will find a lot more information about the error.

---

*Update after error message was added to original post:*

Your error message is a notice about a deprecated function (the `mysql_*` api), an api that should not be used.
You get this notice cause you show all errors (Which is good in development).
I would recommend switching to `mysqli` or `PDO` as the error message says.

I would recommend that any error messages caught by the php script is returned as a failure response with a error message in json, like:

```
die(json_encode(array('result' => false, 'error' => $error)));
```

Instead of just printing them as html or text, this way you can catch them in the java code and handle them as you wish on that side.
You should also set the content type to `application/json` in the php-script, but it should work even without that.

Comment: I have edit my php script and it works perfect but still i got same error in my android studio..

Comment: Did you check the value of the `result` variable? It will tell you whats wrong...

Comment: Yes I have checked it and it give me the whole html code....... but i don't understand why....

Comment: What `whole html code`? Was it an exception? What was the exception? Was it a error message? What was the message?